# How to use optim function in R on my custom Residual Sum of Squares function?

Tags: r, forecasting, optimization, error

I'm trying to use the `optim` function in R to find the optimal values for $\alpha$ and $l_0$ for my custom residual sum of squares (RSS) function, but the values I'm getting back aren't even close to those picked by R's `ses` function, which were $\alpha$ = 0.2971 and $l_0$ = 77260, for the `pigs` dataset in Rob Hyndman's `fpp2` library.

Here's my custom RSS function:

```
custom_rss <- function(ts, alpha, l0) {
  N <- length(ts)
  res <- vector()
  for (j in 1:N-1) {
    y_hat <- custom_ses(ts[1:j], alpha, l0)
    res[j] <- (ts[j+1] - y_hat)^2
  }
  return(sum(res))
}
```

My custom function for simple exponential smoothing is:

```
custom_ses <- function(ts, alpha, l0) {
  N <- length(ts)
  y_hat = 0
  for (j in 1:N-1) {
    y_hat <- y_hat + alpha * ((1 - alpha)^j) * ts[N-j] + ((1 - alpha)^N)*l0
  }
  return(y_hat)
}
```

And finally, here's how I used the `optim` function:

```
optim(par=c(0,1), fn=custom_rss, alpha=0.2971, l0=77260.0561)
```

So, I'm not sure where the problem lies: my SES function, my RSS function, or the way I'm using the `optim` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your objective and smoothing functions are not correct.

More precisely, the problems I found are:

- The way you pass the parameters to the optimizer
- The absence of constraints on the parameters ($\alpha \in [0, 1])$
- The formula for y_hat. I used the Weighted Average Form in https://otexts.org/fpp2/ses.html#eq:7-ses

The parameters to optim() should be passed through the vector par. 
Then, from this vector, you can extract alpha and l0 in your objective function definition. Second, I think it is appropriate to estimate those parameter in such a way you are sure they will respect the necessary constraints. This can be achieved by transforming their values within the optimization routine.

Below you will find a modified example inspired by your R codes above

```
rm(list = ls()); cat("\014"); graphics.off()
library(fpp2)

# Objective function
custom_rss = function(par, ts) 
{
  # Be seure to have \alpha in [0,1]
  alpha = plogis(par[1])
  l0 = par[2]

  N = length(ts)
  fit = custom_ses(ts, alpha, l0)
  res = ts - fit

  out = sum(res^2)/(N-1)
  return(out)
}

# Smoother function      
custom_ses = function(ts, alpha, l0) 
{
  N = length(ts)
  y_hat = c(l0, 0 * (2:N))
  for (j in 1:(N-1))
  {
    new = alpha * ts[j] + (1-alpha) * y_hat[j]
    y_hat[j+1] = new
    # print(y_hat)
  }

  return(y_hat)
}

# The data
data("pigs")
ts = pigs

# optim-based estimates 
est = optim(par = c(0.1, 5000), fn = custom_rss, ts = ts)
alpha = plogis(est$par[1])
l0 = est$par[2]
fit = custom_ses(ts, alpha = alpha, l0 = l0)

# Ses estimates
sesMod = ses(ts)

# Check
cbind(ses = sesMod$model$par, custom = c(alpha, l0))

# Plots
plot(1:length(ts), ts, type = "l", lwd = 1, col = 8)
points(1:length(ts), ts, pch = 16, col = 8, cex = 0.5)
lines(1:length(ts), sesMod$fitted, col = 2, type = "l", lwd = 2)
lines(1:length(ts), fit, col = 3, type = "l", lty = 2,  lwd = 2)
legend("bottomright", legend = c("Data", "ses", "custom"), col = c(8, 2, 3), 
       lty = c(1,1,2), lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Firstly, thank you for helping me out! Next, I understand your changes to my `custom_ses` function, but I don't quite understand your `custom_rss` function. Why did you use the `plogis` function to run on the parameters of the `custom_ses` function? Secondly, why did you use the "BFGS" method for the `optim` function? Keep in mind that I was just going to use the default method, as I don't know anything about the different methods haha.

Comment: Hi, the plogis() just ensures that $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ during the optimization process.The optimization method is important but not too much and you can read a small discussion about the differences between Nelder-Mead and BFGS in the help of optim (and on Wiki of course). You can use the default method but I advice you to start from a more appropriate value of $\lambda_{0}$ as initial value (not 3 as in my initial answer). You can check that est = optim(par = c(0.1, 5000), fn = custom_rss, ts = ts), for example, gives you the same results (as shown in my answer now).

Comment: This is so awesome. I learned so much from your help!!!